# Get todays date in DD MM(String eg. December) YYYY format and add two days

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to display a date in a specific format that is 2/3 days ahead from today's date.

So, if `today is 03.09.2018 (UK Format)`

I want to display

```
05 September 2018
```

Working **Example** - like a delivery company may use.

> Today = 03.09.2018 Your parcel will be delivered on or before 05
>   September 2019 (within 2 Days).

Getting the date pulling through is fine, but changing format and adding the days seems to be giving mixed results.

Comment: Have you tried looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date ?

Answer (score 1):

```
str = '03.09.2018';


split = str.split(".")


date = new Date(split[2],split[1] - 1,split[0]);

date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2); 

monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

toDisplay = date.getDay() + " " + monthNames[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear();
```

"5 September 2018"